# Using an EAR file to create new project in JDeveloper

Tags: jakarta-ee, jar, ear, jdeveloper

I'm not even sure if I worded the question correctly.  I've tried googling, but can't find anything relevant.

Basically I need to create a working project folder in JDeveloper from an ear file.  The ear file is all I have, and I need to be able to modify code.  The ear has a war and the war has numerous jar files.  I have no experience in packaging and deploying files, and obviously even less experience on how to take an ear file and creating a working project folder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

JDeveloper has an option to create a new application from EAR file.  Right click on Applications on the Application Navigator, Select New..., General -> Applications -> Application from EAR file.